# Can a HDInsight in a Vnet connect to a Data Lake Store in a different region?

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake

I don't see Data Lake store service available in North Central US for Azure. So am planning to create it in Central US. Since our HDInsight cluster will be provisioned by infrastructure team in a VNet in North Central US region, am wondering if it will have the ability to connect to a Data lake store in Central US region ?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** HDInsight cluster and the Data Lake Store must be in the same location.

You should create the Data Lake Store in the same region that you plan on creating your HDInsight cluster. If you create the HDInsight cluster in Central US, I would suggest you create Data Lake Store in Central US or vice-versa.

Currently, Azure Data Lake Store available in following regions:

United States:
**East US 2** and 
**Central US**

Europe:
**North Europe**

Comment: Where can I find the roadmap to check when the Data Lake stores will be available in North Central US. ?

Comment: @VijayVeera Currently, there is no such road map. You can check roadmaps for Azure Data Lake Store here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/roadmap/?query=Azure+Data+Lake+Store